# Any way to sort custom object inside array?

Tags: swift, swift4

I have this array

```
var bookTimeArray = [BookTime]()
```

BookTime class contains followings

```
var time : String = ""
var status : String = ""
var booked_by : String = ""
```

Now i need to sort the array bookTimeArray by seeing the BookTime.time variable.

Time variable may contain one time from "12AM" to "11PM"

The object need to be sorted in following pattern

```
["12AM", "1AM", "2AM", "3AM", "4AM", "5AM", "6AM", "7AM", "8AM", "9AM", "10AM", "11AM", "12PM", "1PM", "2PM", "3PM", "4PM", "5PM", "6PM", "7PM", "8PM", "9PM","10PM", "11PM"]
```

if bookTimeArray has 5 object

```
bookTimeArray[0].time = "10AM"
bookTimeArray[1].time = "6AM"
bookTimeArray[2].time = "9AM"
bookTimeArray[3].time = "6PM"
bookTimeArray[4].time = "9PM"
```

**Expected output**

```
bookTimeArray[0].time = "6AM"
bookTimeArray[1].time = "9AM"
bookTimeArray[2].time = "10AM"
bookTimeArray[3].time = "6PM"
bookTimeArray[4].time = "9PM"
```

I cant figure out how to achieve this. Help me out :(

Comment: Array indices in Swift are zero based

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
// First create a DateFormatter object to convert your time strings to Date objects so you can compare between them.
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "ha"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")

// Then you only need to sort the bookTimeArray by *time* property after converting *time* string to a Date object using the dateFormatter that we've created above.
let sortedBooks = bookTimeArray.sorted { dateFormatter.date(from: $0.time)! < dateFormatter.date(from: $1.time)! }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dateFormatter` for creating `Date` objects from your `String` property and then you can sort your array by these `Date`s

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "ha" // format 1AM, 2AM, 12PM, ...
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```

Sorting:

```
bookTimeArray.sort { bookTime1, bookTime2 in
    guard let date1 = dateFormatter.date(from: bookTime1.time), let date2 = dateFormatter.date(from: bookTime2.time) else { return false }
    return date1 < date2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help:

```
// Custom models array   
 let dataArray = [Class(fileID:1),Class(fileID:2),Class(fileID:3)]
// here is sorting code
    dataArray.sorted({ $0.fileID > $1.fileID })
```

Comment: Please edit your answer so as to add an explanation to your code